# Зачем нужно объединение (union)?

Tags: c++, c

Например,

```
union 
{
    float fl,
    unsigned int uinteg,
    char ch,
    int integ
} foo;
```

Все это хранится вперемешку в одной области памяти. Какой в этом смысл, ведь однажды установив значения

```
foo.fl = 3.14f;
foo.uinteg = 666;
foo.ch = 'a';
foo.int = -25;
```

уже не получится получить их назад - все перемешается? Способ сэкономить пару байтов или пару тактов и при этом сохранить читабельность? Не писать 4 разных функции, а написать одну, которая принимает `union` и в ней уже решать, что делать? В таком случае не проще ли принять `void *` и потом кастануть в тот тип, какой нужен? Как пример "Просто кастануть" приведу такой код:

Классический пример:

```
typedef enum { STR, INT } tType;
typedef struct {
    tType typ;          // typ is separate.
    union {
        int ival;       // ival and sval occupy same memory.
        char *sval;
    };
} tVal;

void printer(tVal uni)
{
    if (uni.type == INTEGER) // blah-blah
        uni.ival // Используем integer
    else
        ini.sval // В противном случае
}
```

Функцию принтер можно переписать как-то так:

```
void printer(void* data, tType typ)
{
    if (tType == INTEGER)
    {
        (int*)data // Чего-то делаем
    }
}
```

Другой пример:

```
union 
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
} bar;

bar.a = 20;
bar.b = 50; // Значение a потеряли :(
```

Опять-таки какой в этом смысл, если я могу сначала завести отдельную переменную `int a = 20;` а затем изменю ее значение `a = 50;` и эффект точно такой же? Выглядит как сильное колдовство.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Union*-ы (объединения) используют в двух случаях:

1. **Для создания «универсального» типа данных**, способного хранить не единственный, а *один из предопределённых* типов. Для этого к объединению добавляют целочисленное поле, указывающее тип хранимых в настоящий момент данных:

   ```
   struct variant
   {
       union tag_value
       {
           int intValue;
           float floatValue
       } value;
       unsigned storedType;
   };
   ```

   Один из примеров подобного применения в реальной жизни — структура [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627(v=vs.85).aspx) из Windows API.

   Иными словами, это предшественник современных `boost::variant`, `QVariant` и т. д. Однако вышеперечисленные классы могут хранить в себе непримитивные типы (с конструкторами, деструкторами и операторами копирования), а `union` — нет.
2. **Для преобразования между несовместимыми типами.** Традиционно для этих целей используют оператор преобразования `(T)`, либо `reinterpret_cast<>`. Однако эти способы опасны нарушением *[strict aliasing rule](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114117/)* и, как результат, порождением неопределённого (то есть непредсказуемого) поведения.

   Правильные способы преобразования — это либо `memcpy` (подобный вызов которого выбрасывается компилятором), либо использование `union`-а.

   ***UPD:*** Внимание! Преобразование через `union` является допустимым **только в Си**, но не в C++. В [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11996970/2553424) на вопрос «Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?» приводятся отсылки на следующие пункты стандартов:

   - *[c11](/questions/tagged/c11)*

     > ***6.5.2.3 Структуры и члены объединений***
     >
     > *95) Если поле, используемое для чтения содержимого объекта-объединения, не является полем, использованным ранее для записи значения в этот объект, требуемая часть внутреннего представления объекта интерпретируется в соответствием с представлением затребованного типа согласно 6.2.6 (данный процесс известен также как type punning). Это представление может приводить к неопределённому поведению.*
     >
     > ---
     >
     > ***6.5.2.3 Structure and union members***
     >
     > *95) If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation.*
   - *[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) (нет явного разрешения type punning-а)*

     > ***9.5 Объединения [class.union]***
     >
     > *В объединении в каждый момент времени может быть активно только одно нестатическое поле; вследствие этого в объединении в любой момент времени может находиться не более одного значения.*
     >
     > ---
     >
     > ***9.5 Unions [class.union]***
     >
     > *In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time.*

Comment: А разве union не приводит к такому же ub? Мне казалось что читать можно только в то поле в которое писал.

Comment: Тут возникает вопрос - зачем универсальный тип? Для удобства? `VARIANT` из WinAPI не выглядит удобным - аж кровь из глаз потекла. Чем `void*` + второй параметр с типом не угодил как универсальный? `printf` вот может печатать что угодно и туда не нужно никаких хитрых структур передавать. Или это дело вкуса?

Comment: @pavel, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @m9_psy, `void*` требует дополнительного выделения памяти в куче (ибо указатель). Union же всё хранит в себе.

Comment: @Arhad: trap representation — это, как я понимаю, не «некорректное значение», это «значение, при чтении которого происходит UB». Так что разница между C и C++ не такая уж и большая.

Comment: @VladD, `Так что разница между C и C++ не такая уж и большая` — ключевое слово стандарта  C11 — ***might** be a trap* (то есть в общем случае разрешено). Могу предположить, что UB возникает при несовместимости *memory layout* исходного и конечного типов.

Comment: @VladD, `это, как я понимаю...` — дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Arhad: Ага, спасибо! Надеюсь, так будет понятнее для читателей.

Answer (score 8):

Один из практических способов использование `union` это доступ к битам передаваемой информации. Допустим передается информация по битно за один раз 32 бита.

```
struct _info_s 
{
  uint32_t info_a:2;
  uint32_t info_b:10;
  uint32_t info_c:8;      
  uint32_t info_d:5;
  uint32_t info_e:5;
  uint32_t info_f:2;
}__atributte__((packed));
typedef struct _info_s  info_s;

union _total_u
{
 uint32_t array;
 info_s info;
};
```

При чтении/записи мы можем сразу оперировать `uint32_t`, но и доступ к битам появляется сразу.

Comment: а у Вас почему 33 Бита в сумме? ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Вот что мне в своё время на похожий вопрос ответил Бьёрн Страуструп:

> Unions are used when you want to save space by reusing space for 
>   information one type at a time. I don't use them much.

Иными словами, в наше время они, в общем-то не нужны.

Comment: Не нужны, однако, используются. Я натолкнулся на них (и по незнанию принял за структуру и недоумевал) в [Vulkan API](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/VkClearValue.html) - свежачок, год как вышел. Самое, что ни на есть "наше время".

Comment: @m9_psy, используются, да. Но, как вы сказали, сейчас это скорее колдовство.

Comment: Если не думать о памяти (о кэше процессора, передаче аргументов функций в регистрах и т.п. не значимых для современных программистах вещах), то пожалуй и не нужны (всегда можно заменить просто структурой)

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял, то это совмещение переменных в памяти. Иногда оч удобно, если хочется переменную увидеть в другом свете или требуется получить доступ только к части переменной...

К примеру String можно интерпритировать как массив byte[] или прямоугольный массив byte[][2], a integer разложить на byte_lo и byte_hi

Comment: То, о чём вы говорите, есть undefined behaviour в C++ (и скорее всего в C). Загляните в ответ @Arhad.

Answer (score 0):

*union* очень полезная штука при работе с микроконтроллерами когда необходимо обрабатывать данные поступающие в "сыром" виде (например при передаче по CAN-сети или ethernet).
Например, при передаче по информационной сети возможны два тип сообщений:

```
typedef struct{
 char id;
 unsigned int code1;
 unsigned int code2;
}Msg1;

typedef struct{
 char id;
 char code_error;
}Msg2;
```

Cоздаем объединение

```
union{
 char data[maxLen];
 Msg1 msg1;
 Msg2 msg2;
}DATA;
```

Создаем переменную

```
DATA data;
```

Запись получаемых данных ведем в переменную `data.data`, а интерпретацию данных в сообщениях при помощи значений `data.msg1` или `data.msg2`.

Также можно обойтись и без union напрямую преобразовывая указать на "сырые" данные в указатель одного из видов сообщений и работать с полями сообщений, но при включении оптимизации (например -O2 или -O3) такой код перестает работать. Необходимо везде при объявлении переменных добавлять ключевое слово `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже описывалось, union очень полезен при работе с микроконтроллерами, например, для экономии памяти можно объявить структуру флагов (или значений), привязать размер в битах и добавить переменную сопоставимую с нужным размером битов.

```
typedef union {
 struct {
  bool flag1:1;
  bool flag2:1;
  bool flag3:1;
  bool flag4:1;
  bool flag5:1;
  uint8_t param:3; 
 };   // итого 8 битов
 uint8_t flags;   // переменная такого же размера или больше
}FLAGS;
```