# Неявное приведение типов данных

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Казалось бы ничего сложного тут нет:

```
int a = 5; /// Тут при сложении int + float логично получить float, но мы получаем double (почему?)
float b = 3.14; /// когда идет присвоение смотрится тип и к нему притирается ответ (тут все ясно)
float c = a + b; /// Не ясно когда выполняются операции между типами иногда не понимаешь какой тип в результате операции мы имеем
```

Вопрос в том какие типы данных получаются в результате преобразований в разных случаях:

```
char+int
char+float
char+double
int+float
int+double
char+unsigned char
int+unsigned int
float+unsigned float
итд
```

P.S Однозначных ответов в интернете не нашел

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Тут при сложении int + float логично получить float, но мы получаем double (почему?)

Я не вижу, о каком "тут" вы ведете речь, но при сложении `int` и `float` получается именно `float`. Причем в вашем же примере ниже вы пишете

```
int+float // операнд типа int приводится к типу float
```

что верно (и противоречит написанному вами выше).

В языке С времен динозавров (хотя может и в K&R), действительно производилось автоматическое приведение операндов типа `float` к типу `double`, но эти времена уже давно ушли. В стандартизованном С такого никогда не было, хотя отголоски этого поведения по сих пор сохраняются при вызове непрототипизированных или variadic функций, где аргументы типа `float` таки преобразуются к типу `double`.

> Однозначных ответов в интернете не нашел

Поведение описано в стандарте языка, хотя алгоритм многоэтажен. В моем [упрощенном] переводе

- Если один из операндов имеет тип `long double`, то и второй операнд приводится к типу `long double`
- В противном случае, если один из операндов имеет тип `double`, то и второй операнд приводится к типу `double`
- В противном случае, если один из операндов имеет тип `float`, то и второй операнд приводится к типу `float`
- В противном случае оба операнда подвергаются integer promotions<sup>1</sup> и далее рассматриваются типы после promotions

  - Если оба операнда имеют одинаковый тип, ничего делать не надо
  - В противном случае, если оба операнда имеют знаковый тип или оба операнда имеют беззнаковый тип, то операнд с меньшим рангом<sup>2</sup> конвертируется к типу операнда с большим рангом
  - В противном случае, если один операнд имеет беззнаковый тип и ранг, который выше или равен рангу второго операнда, то знаковый операнд конвертируется к типу беззнакового операнда
  - В противном случае, если диапазон значений знакового операнда достаточен для представления всех значений беззнакового операнда, то беззнаковый операнд конвертируется к типу знакового операнда
  - В противном случае, оба операнда конвертируются к беззнаковому типу, соответствующему<sup>3</sup> типу знакового операнда

1) *Integer promotions* - преобразования "малых" целых типов `_Bool`, `[signed/unsigned] char`, `[signed/unsigned] short` к типу `int` (если диапазон `int` достаточен) или к `unsigned int` (в противном случае).

2) *Ранг* - это фактически положение типа в "естественной" последовательности целочисленных типов: `_Bool`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`. (Приставки `signed`/`unsigned` на ранг не влияют.)

3) Имеется в виду, что типу `int` соответствует тип `unsigned int`, типу `long` соответствует тип `unsigned long` и т.д.

Несложно видеть, что с формальной точки зрения механизм определения результирующего типа - платформенно-зависим, ибо опирается на соотношения диапазонов представимых значений разных целочисленных типов.

Например, невозможно дать универсального однозначного ответа на вопрос о типе `char+int`. На привычной нам платформе с 8-битным `char` и 32-битным `int` это будет `int`. Однако на более экзотической платформе с беззнаковым 16-битным `char` и 16-битным `int` это будет `unsigned int`.

---

О теме, поднятой в комментариях:

А почему сделано именно так, а не по-другому? Темна вода во облацех. Однако я лично, как человек, рьяно придерживающийся в своем коде принципа "используй беззнаковые типы для представления натурально беззнаковых значений", вижу, что в моем коде подавляющее большинство целочисленных значений - беззнаковые. И это при том, что работая в области вычислительной геометрии, я часто сталкиваюсь с некомбинаторными задачами и натурально неположительными значениями (координаты и т.п.) Программы, как правило, доминируются комбинаторикой, и большинство значений в них - натурально неотрицательны. А в тех областях, где знаковые значения преобладают, проблемы смешения знаковых и беззнаковых операндов обычно не возникает вообще. Поэтому мне выбор в пользу беззнакового типа в смешанной "`int` vs. `unsigned`" операции кажется вполне естественным.

Также можно привести рассуждения из "C99 Rationale" на родственную тему о том, почему integer promotions пошли по другому пути и предпочитают расширять малые типы до *знакового* `int`. Обратите внимание, что там тоже упоминается вопрос "`int` vs. `unsigned`", а также то, что компиляторы в системе UNIX всегда предпочитали приведение к беззнаковому типу. (Перевод мой.)

> Между моментом публикации K&R и разработкой С89 возникли серьезные расхождения между разными реализациями в области правил integer promotions. Реализации разделились на два разных лагеря, которые можно условно охарактеризовать как *Сохраняющие Беззнаковость* и *Сохраняющие Значение*. Различия между этими подходами заключалось в трактовке типов `unsigned char` и `unsigned short` при их расширении в процессе integer promotions. (Принятое решение также повлияло на типизацию констант.)
>
> *Сохраняющий Беззнаковость* подход предполагает расширение двух малых беззнаковых типов до `unsigned int`. Это простое правило, которое не зависит от среды выполнения.
>
> *Сохраняющий Значение* подход предполагает расширение этих типов до `signed int`, если этот тип может представлять все значения исходного типа, и до `unsigned int` в противном случае. Таким образом, если в некоей среде выполнения `short` представляется как что-то меньшее, чем `int`, то `unsigned short` превращается в `int`. В противном случае он становится `unsigned int`.
>
> Оба подхода дают один и тот же ответ в подавляющем большинстве случаев. И оба приводят к одному и тому же результату в еще большем числе случаев в реализациях, основанных на арифметике в дополнительном коде и с "тихим" заворачиванием значения при возникновении знакового переполнения. То есть в большинстве современных реализаций. В таких реализациях различия между подходами проявляются только при одновременном соблюдении двух условий:
>
> 1. Выражение, включающее `unsigned char` или `unsigned short`, порождает результат ширины `int`, в котором установлен знаковый бит. Т.е. это либо унарная операция над одним из этих типов, либо бинарная операция, в которой вторым операндом является `int` или более "узкий" тип.
> 2. Результат вышеупомянутого выражения используется в контексте, в котором знаковость имеет значение
>
>    - `sizeof(int) < sizeof(long)` и результат должен быть расширен до типа `long`
>    - это левый операнд `>>` в реализации, где сдвиги являются арифметическими
>    - это любой операнд `/`, `%`, `<`, `<=`, `>` или `>=`.
>
> В таких условиях возникает настоящая неоднозначность в интерпретации. Результат можно назвать *сомнительно знаковым*, потому что можно привести аргументы как в пользу знаковой, так и в пользу беззнаковой интерпретации. Та же самая неоднозначность возникает и всякий раз, когда `unsigned int` и `signed int` встречаются по разные стороны бинарного оператора, и при этом `signed int` имеет отрицательное значение. Ни один из вариантов не лучше и не хуже другого в вопросе разрешения этой неоднозначности. Если вдруг отрицательный `signed int` превращается в огромный `unsigned int`, это может для кого-то оказаться неожиданностью. Или наоборот, это может являться именно тем, что хотел получить опытный программист. (Разумеется, всех этих неоднозначностей можно избежать путем продуманного применения кастов.)
>
> Правила *Сохраняющего Беззнаковость* подхода существенно увеличивают количество ситуаций, в которых `unsigned int` сталкивается с `signed int`, приводя к *сомнительно знаковому* результату, в то время как правила *Сохраняющего Значение* подхода минимизируют такие столкновения. По этой причине *Сохраняющий Значение* подход был признан более безопасным для новичка или для неосторожного программиста. После длительных дискуссий Комитет С89 принял решение в пользу *Сохраняющего Значение* подхода, несмотря на тот факт, что компиляторы C системы UNIX к тому времени эволюционировали в направлении *Сохраняющего Беззнаковость* подхода.

Comment: @int3: Нет, ничего плохого в этом примере нет. Тип `char` в языках С и С++ *по определению* имеет размер в один *языковый* байт.  А вот сколько *битов* в этом байте - не оговаривается (их там `CHAR_BIT`). И их может быть 8, 10, 16, 32 - сколько угодно. Т.е. нет ничего удивительного в платформах, где `sizeof(char) == sizeof(short) == sizeof(int) == 1`, и при этом все эти типы имеют внутри 16 бит. Или 32 бит. В embedded мире такие платформы реально существуют.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53973/discussion-on-answer-by-ant----).

Answer (score 3):

Ответ надо искать в стандарте C или на форумах, посвященных обсуждению стандарта C, в частности на форумах, расположенных на google.com или isocpp.org.

Для вычисления общего типа операндов операций к арифметическим типам применяются так называемые *обычные арифметические преобразования*.

Например, в описании бинарного оператора + написано в стандарте C (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 4 If both operands have arithmetic type, **the usual arithmetic
>   conversions** are performed on them.

И (стандарат C, 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause
>   conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to
>   determine a common real type for the operands and result. For the
>   speciﬁed operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
>   domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real
>   type. Unless explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also
>   the corresponding real type of the result, whose type domain is the
>   type domain of the operands if they are the same, and complex
>   otherwise. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions:
>
> First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is long
>   double, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain,
>   to a type whose corresponding real type is long double.
>
> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double,
>   the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a
>   type whose corresponding real type is double.
>
> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float,
>   the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a
>   type whose corresponding real type is float.
>
> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then
>   the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>   needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>   unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer
>   conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with greater
>   rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted
>   to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

В частности, как написано выше

> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float,
>   the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a
>   type whose corresponding real type is float

То есть в этом фрагменте кода

```
int a = 5;
float b = 3.14;
float c = a + b;
```

операнд `a` выражения `a + b` приводится к типу `float` и результат выражения так же имеет тип `float`.

Если в выражении отсутствуют операнды с плавающей запятой, то

> Otherwise, **the integer promotions** are performed on both operands.
>   Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands

Например,

```
char+int // операнд типа char приводится к типу int 
char+float // операнд типа char приводится к типу float 
char+double // операнд типа char приводится к типу double 
int+float // операнд типа int приводится к типу float 
int+double // операнд типа int приводится к типу double
char+unsigned char // оба операндв приводятся к типу int
int+unsigned int // операнд типа int приводится к типу unsigned int 
float+unsigned float // тип unsigned float отсутствует; ошибка компиляции
```

Относительно данного примера

```
char+unsigned char // оба операндв приводятся к типу int
```

хотел бы добавить, что тип `char` может вести себя либо как тип `signed char` либо как тип `unsigned char` в зависимости от установленных опций компилятора.

Вот пример на влияние применения *integer promotions* к целочисленным типам

```
unsigned short a = 5; 
unsigned short b = 10;
```

Значение `a - b`  для переменных, объявленных выше, будет отрицательным числом, так как обе переменные в выражении будут приведены к типу `int`. В то время, как значение `x - y` для переменных, объявленных ниже, будет положительным числом.

```
unsigned int x = 5; 
unsigned int y = 10;
```

Comment: Было бы круто, если под английскими цитатами был перевод на русском.

Comment: @EgorSmolyakov, почему «под»? [Можно и «над»](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/623550/208074) (нижняя часть ответа).

Comment: Пару вопросов:
1. Если первый тип int, а второй unsigned int - при сложении будет тип unsigned int, а при вычитании int?
2. Если первый тип char, а второй unsigned char, почему приводится к типу int? (можно же ведь было привести и к unsigned char ну или short int)

Comment: @MaximPro 1) При сложении и при вычитании оба операнда приводятся к типу unsigned int и результат также будет этого типа. 2) все типы, ранг которых меньше типа int приводятся к типу int.

Comment: Хорошо но я не понял про первый вопрос: почему именно unsigned int? При вычитании тип unsigned int не обеспечивает ни одного отрицательного значения

Comment: @MaximPro Смотрите правила обычных арифметических преобразований.

Comment: Все равно не понял -_- (понятно что приводится к большему типу из операндов, в данном случае размер операндов одинаков...иии что???)

Comment: @MaximPro Дело в том, что без-знаковые числа могут представлять внутренне как битовую комбинацию все значения знаковых чисел того же ранга.

Comment: Это понятно что unsigned то же что и signed у которого старший бит это знак -. Ну и что с того? Битов то ведь одинаковое количество! А значит комбинаций то же одинаковое количество

Comment: @MaximPro Это связано с аппаратными архитектурами. Для некоторых архитектур переполнение отрицательного числа при операциях может вызвать прерывание.