# Приведение типов, C, char - int

Tags: c

Читаю книгу Пратча по Си и тут возник вопрос по приведению типов и типу `char`. В конце главы (посвященной приведению типов) автор пишет, что `char` и `short` повышаются до `double` всякий раз, когда используются в аргументах ф-ций. И тут я не понимаю: вроде в каждой ф-ции явно задается тип входящих аргументов, в ф-ции расчет идет согласно этим типам... Что имел в виду автор? И еще, когда выражение типа: `а = 'х' + 'в'` - то будет ли приведение типа до `double` в этом случае?

PS. Я написал прогу, которая составляет судоку и в основе использовал массивы `char`, а не `int`. Мне изначально показалось, что использование `int` нецелесообразно, так как используются всего 9 значений. Но теперь, когда почитал немного больше материала по программированию, начинаю думать о правильности этого решения. Как я понял из прочитанного, комп заточен именно под тип `int` и все операции будут проходить быстрее именно с ним, к тому же при операциях происходит приведение к типу `int`, если используется числовая константа или константа. `Char` выигрывает по месту, но, в моем случае, главное именно производительность - так насколько быстрее комп работает с `int`? Стоит ли, в дальнейшем отдавать предпочтение именно `int`?

Comment: Про приведение типов в выражениях был вопрос: [Неявное приведение типов данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627522)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Про приведение `char` и `int` к `double` - это или вы что-то не так поняли, или в книге не так написано. Если функция принимает `double` - ну тогда, конечно...

Что до скорости - думаю, для Судоку некритично :), но вообще говоря, `int` обычно быстрее. Но опять же, играют роль разные факторы - где именно хранятся значения (типа - `int` в памяти медленнее `char`'а в регистре :)). Но в своих программах наблюдал ускорение.

Кстати, формально есть типы `int_fast8_t`, `int_fast16_t`, `int_fast32_t`, `int_fast64_t` - теоретически если нужна именно скорость доступа, то можно использовать их, а компилятор сам знает, что использовать. Например, в VC++ 2015 что `int_fast16_t`, что `int_fast32_t` - оба 4-байтовые. (Кстати, на SO этот вопрос [обсуждался](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254051/the-difference-of-int8-t-int-least8-t-and-int-fast8-t)).

Comment: По-поводу double: в книге (199 ст) написано ровно то, что я приводил выше - можете проверить, это резюме главы, начало 4-ого обзаца.

Comment: Нашел, мда... Сейчас поищу оригинал, посмотрим, что там.

Comment: В оригинале - *In C, many type conversions take place automatically. The `char` and `short` types are promoted to type* **`int`** *whenever they appear in expressions or as function arguments.* Можете зайти на сайт http://www.williamspublishing.com/ и высказать свое справедливое "фе"...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Какое-то у вас неправильное издание. У меня есть эта книга 6-е издание, Вильямс, 2015 год. Так вот, там это резюме находится на 192 странице и там написано, что *"повышаются до типа int всякий раз, когда используются в выражениях или в качестве аргументов функций, не имеющих прототипа"*.

Comment: @Harry я не знаю английский.

Comment: @zed у меня 5-ое издание, 2013 год. Да, смысл написанного координально отличается. К тому же еще и выражения? Видимо перевод говеный. Тоесть в выражении а = 'х'; а = а + 'в' - сначала оператор а будет повышен до double, потом вычисление, а потом присваение оператору урезанного значения, так?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch В выражениях типа `'a' + 'b'` char приводится к int.

Comment: @zed ясно, спасибо. Если честно, я в шоке от этого вот момента: мало того, что в 5-ом издании вместо int укпзан double, так еще и ничего не сказано про выражения! А про ф-ции не указано, что "без прототипа"... Это как понимать? Остается только догадываться сколько касеков в переводе до и после этого момента!

Comment: @zed В выражениях типа `'a' + 'b'` нет приведения к `int` - поскольку тип литерала наподобие `'a'` в языке C *и есть `int`*, а не `char`. Это просто суммирование двух `int`'ов.