# Способ представления знаковых целых в C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

В стандарте языка указано, что для для представления целочисленных типов (*integral types*) допускается использовать один из трёх способов:

- *2's complement*,
- *1's complement*,
- *signed magnitude*.

В связи с чем возникает несколько вопросов:

1. В настоящее время где-нибудь вообще используется представление целых чисел, отличное от *2's complement*?
2. Допускает ли стандарт, чтобы в рамках одной и той же реализации использовались различные представления для целочисленных типов? Например, чтобы `char` был *2's complement*, а `int` был *1's complement*?
3. Как различные представления целых согласуются с битовыми операциями? Например, пусть есть такой код:

   ```
   unsigned char a = 1;    
   a = ~a;
   ```

И пусть в некоторой реализации используется восьмибитный `char` и шестнадцатибитный `int`, и для представления целых знаковых чисел применяется ***1's*** complement, т.е. отрицательные значения мы храним в обратном коде. У меня сложилось впечатление, что для вычисления значения переменной `a` *могут быть* проделаны следующие преобразования:

1. Переменная `a` подвергнется целочисленному расширению до `int`, ибо операнд битового отрицания, согласно стандарту, может быть расширен. Т.е. набор битов `00000001` преобразуется в `00000000 00000001`.
2. Произойдёт инвертирование битов, т.е. расширенное значение примет вид `11111111 11111110`.
3. Данная последовательность бит будет интерпретироваться как знаковое целое, ибо, согласно стандарту, результат битового отрицания имеет тип расширенного операнда. Данная последовательность бит в обратном коде означает целое число `-1`.
4. Целое число `-1` будет приведено к беззнаковому целому `unsigned char` по модулю `256`. Т.е. переменная `a` примет значение `255`, которое кодируется следующей последовательностью бит: `11111111`. Что несколько странно, ибо используя битовое отрицание к последовательности бит `00000001`, я ожидаю получить `11111110`, а не `11111111`.

Допускается ли стандартом такая работа битового отрицания, или приведённый выше пример в корне не верен?

Comment: Я так понимаю, все эти понятия синонимичны понятиям прямого, обратного и дополнительного кода?

Comment: @megorit, да, вы правы. Стоит заметить, что начиная с C++20 данный вопрос не актуален, т.к. там допускается только один способ представления целочисленных типов — two’s complement (дополнительный код).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Говорят, что системы типа UNISYS 2200 ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_1100/2200_series#UNISYS_2200_series), [2](http://www.unisys.com/offerings/clearpath-forward/clearpath-forward-products/clearpath-forward-dorado-systems)) еще встречаются кое-где в реальной жизни. Штатный компилятор С в этих системах использует 1's-complement представление.

   См. также

   [Are there any non-twos-complement implementations of C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276957/are-there-any-non-twos-complement-implementations-of-c)
   [Exotic architectures the standards committees care about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standards-committees-care-about)
2. Прямого запрета на смешение представлений в стандарте нет. Да и нет в таком запрете никакого смысла, ибо никакой пользы он бы не принес - стандарт и так не гарантирует вам никакой "синхронизированности" между представлениями разных знаковых целых типов. Например, каждый целый тип может обладать своим количеством и расположением padding-битов.
3. Ваша интерпретация работы оператора `~` совершенно верна. Да, такое поведение допускается. Да, поведение "малых" *беззнаковых* типов в таких контекстах существенно зависит от выбранного представления *знаковых* типов. Точнее, побитовое поведение знаковых типов очевидным образом зависит от выбранного представления, а "малые" *беззнаковые* типы уже становятся заложниками этого поведения через посредство integral promotions.

   Можно также отметить, что применение `~` к знаковому значению может породить и trap representation.

   (Свою роль тут также сыграл сделанный на этапе формирования C89/90 выбор в пользу выполнения расширения беззнаковых типов к *знаковому* `int`, как описано в Rationale к стандарту (см. вторую часть моего ответа [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627526/182825)), вопреки имевшей место тогда юниксовой традиции расширения беззнаковых типов к `unsigned int`.)