# Язык C, странное поведение при сравнении знаковых и беззнаковых

Tags: c, compare, signed

Я абсолютно не понимаю, почему происходит то, что происходит:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    signed char sc = -1;
    unsigned char uc = 1;

    if (sc < uc)// Фактически, (UCHAR_MAX < 1)
    {
        printf("<\n");// Выводит это, магия...
    } else {
        printf(">=\n");
    }

    signed int si = -1;
    unsigned int ui = 1;

    if (si < ui)// Фактически, (UINT_MAX < 1)
    {
        printf("<\n");
    } else {
        printf(">=\n");// Выводит это, все верно.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Логично предполагать, что при сравнении знакового и беззнакового оба операнда приводятся к самому широкому типу в выражении - к беззнаковому. Следовательно, при сравнении **sc** с **uc** первый операнд должен приводиться к **unsigned char**.

Но почему-то это не так.

Comment: при сравнении знакового и беззнакового - это "неопределённое поведение", многие компиляторы выдают warning. Более строгие языки просто запрещают так сравнивать. Я плохо знаком с "неопределённым поведением" более опытные вам чётче скажут. Могу только сказать что си транслирует код в ассемблер, а там не хватает разрядной сетки для перевода, а операции сравнения беззнакового с знаковым - нету.

Comment: Странно, в Стандарте написано, что если сравнивается знаковое и беззнаковое, то знаковое конвертируется в беззнаковое.

Comment: warning компилятор выдаёт? Попробуйте под разными компиляторами. Мой борланд делает тоже второе + варнинг + даже если поменять местами.

Comment: Предупреждает о сравнении знакового и беззнакового. Всегда считал, что это предупреждение нужно для того, чтобы намекнуть, что при приведении знакового к беззнаковому может нарушится логика, например в циклах. Короче, предупреждение предупреждает о том, что там возникает неявное приведение к беззнаковому. Тут вряд ли UB. Такое ощущение, что тип char при сравнениях приводится к short или int. Но я не понимаю, почему это происходит.

Comment: Логично предполагать, что при сравнении знакового и беззнакового будет ошибка компиляции. Однако в С++ происходят совершенно нелогичные цепочки integral promotions (которые изначально вроде как производились для подстройки под регистры процессоров).

Comment: Все типы меньше размера чем **int** преобразуются в знаковый **int**.

Comment: @nick_n_a, нет там никакого неопределённого поведения.

Comment: @Максим, UB нет, а вот implementation-defined - возможно есть, поскольку зависит от размерности типов.

Comment: @AlexGlebe: Все типы меньше размера чем `int` преобразуются в знаковый `int` или в беззнаковый `int`, в зависимости от свойств платформы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Неявное приведение типов данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627522/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, мне удалось найти точный ответ на мой вопрос. Все дело в продвижении целых чисел.

Стандарт говорит, что любой тип, меньший (рангом-битовой шириной), чем **int**, перед любыми операциями преобразуется в **int**, если **int** способен представить все значения исходного типа, иначе тип преобразуется в **unsigned int**.

И лишь после **integral promotion** начинаются стандартные преобразования, которые преобразуют все аргументы операции к общему типу.

Вот самое понятное обсуждение из всех, которые мне удалось найти:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню:

1. Все числа, имеющие размерность меньше int увеличиваются до int.
2. Меньшее число расширяется до размерности большего с сохранением знаковости.
3. Если получились два числа, отличающиеся только знаковостью, то сравнение выполняется над беззнаковыми.

Получается, в первом примере оба расширяются до знаковых int'ов: -1 и 255, а во втором правый int беззнаковый, поэтому -1 тоже рассматривается как -1U.

Обращаю внимание, что если бы разимеры char и int были одинаковы (вроже, стандарт такое разрешает), выполнялось бы беззнаковое сравнение.

Comment: "Язык C прост и предсказуем" - самая наглая ложь, которую я слышал в своей жизни. Спасибо за объяснение!

Comment: @Максим, немного переписал ответ, впрочем суть та же.

Comment: @Максим, как язык C - прост до банальности. Но вот когда начинаются манипуляции и прочие хитровыверты, особенно с завязкой на железо...