# Почему при перемножении переменных разных типов получаются разные ответы?

Tags: c++, переменные, int, переполнение

```
int x = 1000000; // (10 ^ 6)
long res = x * x;
cout << res; // вывод получается неправильным.

long int x = 1000000;
long res = x * x;
cout << res; // теперь же вывод правильный.
```

Не понимаю, в чем проблема. Ведь в int точно входит 10 ^ 6, а в long 10 ^ 18.

Comment: Это UB. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: В C++ при умножении типы приводятся к одному и результат становится этим же типом. Не важно, что у вас слева стоит long, в него попадут уже вычисленное значение справа. А справа по итогу int * int -> int, long * long -> long, int * long -> long и т.д. Вот и выходит long = (int * int -> int) с переполнением.

Comment: [Неявное приведение типов данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/627522).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int x = 1000000; // (10 ^ 6)
long res = x * x;
```

Вычисляется `x*x` - как произведение двух `int`, а значит, и результат `int`. "Втискиваем" 10<sup>12</sup> в `int`, а потом присваиваем `long`.

Что не так?...

И, кстати, в `long` далеко не везде входит 10<sup>18</sup>, это зависит от конкретного компилятора.

Comment: Тогда не очень понятно, почему пример с short и int работает корректно:
    short n = 32767;
    int x = n * n;
    std::cout << x;

Comment: потому что сумма двух short это int.

Comment: @kislyakoff, насколько я помню минимальный тип результата int, поэтому с типами ниже все будет нормально. Своего рода исключение из правил, чтобы код работал быстрее за счёт выравнивания: short * short -> int * int -> int.

Comment: там такой пункт - [intergral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

Answer (score 3):

Если вы перемножаете две переменные одного типа, то и результат будет этого типа, но только если размер этих типов не меньше `int`. Иначе происходит преобразование к `int` и результат так же возвращен будет в `int`.

Например:

```
short x = 32767;
int res = x * x; //short < int => будет перемножение двух int-ов =>
// => и результат будет возвращен типа int
// аналогично будет работать например с unsigned char
```

Такой процесс преобразования типов называется: ["Неявное преобразование типов"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

То есть, когда вы пишите:

```
int x = 1000000;
long res = x * x; //Перемножение int-ов => и результат возвращается int
```

Т.к. результат возвращается типа `int`, то происходит переполнение и вот после этого, это значение присваивается `long res`.

Чтобы исправить эту проблему, нужно один из множителей привести к большему типу, чем `int` в вашем случае `long`.

```
int x = 1000000;
long res = (long)x * x;
```

Так же стоит сказать про, то что `long`, как и `long long` и другие подобные типы данных. На разных компиляторах могут иметь разный размер => и диапазон значений другой.

Лично у меня на `Visual Studio 2019` `long` и `int` одного размера :)

Можно использовать типы данных, размер которых не изменяется.

Например:

```
#include <climits>
...
int32_t x = 1000000;
int64_t res = (int64_t)x * x;
...
```

Comment: "*Если вы перемножаете две переменные одного типа, то и результат будет этого типа.*" - не обязательно.