# Какой тип нужно задать переменной

Tags: c

Вычислите значение выражения z % x – x / y и укажите тип этого значения, если объявлено следующие переменные:
long x  = -6; int y = -12;  int z = -21; Само выражение будет равно -3, но ...

У меня с приятелем возник спор на счет этого, так как мы оба не понимаем какой тип корректней будет придать результату выражения.

Comment: long, т.к. [неявное приведение типов данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/627522)

Comment: Корректней не смешивать в одном арифметическом выражении встроенные переменные разных типов, так как это приводит к неявным преобразованиям.

Comment: @user7860670 это задание в универе, сам я такое не писал бы...

Comment: Олимпиады еще не все закончились что ли?)))

Comment: Экзамены... а там такую чушь иногда спрашивают что лучше выучить по глубже чтобы не было к чему докопаться.

Comment: Это вполне нормальный вопрос. Про приведение типов знать нужно, чтобы в дальнейшем не недоумевать, почему `long long x = 2000000000 * 3` считает [не правильно](https://ideone.com/ru5LQ6).

Comment: Правильнее будет выбрать ```float``` или ```double``` т.к. результат вовсе не равен трём (z % x = -3, x/y = 0,5   ответ -3.5). Т.е. вы теряете десятичную часть, получаете [неправильный ответ](https://onlinegdb.com/9dBhJRYfb). Так что возможно вопрос стоит открыть заново, т.к. ответ к ошибке крылся не в неявном приведении)

Comment: @SelfishCrawler На сколько помню, при целочисленных операндах результат деления будет тоже целочисленный. Так что при заданных условиях `x/y = 0`

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов ну так у автора изначально типы данных выбраны неправильно. Я так понимаю, само задание это "вычислите значение выражения". А long и int это уже наработки автора, соответственно правильного значения он не получит.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler не думаю, что Вы правильно понимаете. Выбранные типы, скорее всего, определены в задании, а не автором. И сами являются частью задания, представляя собой небольшую ловушку для невнимательных.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов может и так